# Can i completely change my question or should i ask another?

Tags: discussion

I realised after I wrote my question [How large can a flying insect get and still be able to walk upside down?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/164648/how-large-can-a-flying-insect-get-and-still-be-able-to-walk-upside-down) that it was pretty vague and the first answer confirmed that, so as I went to edit the question I realised I wanted to change it completely as I now have the weight of the creature but want to know what environmental conditions would be needed for it to walk upside down.
I didn't want to change it after another answer as this would be unfair and I may get interesting answers anyways.
should I edit the question completely or write another question later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have answers you should leave it and ask a new one. You shouldn't edit a question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers.